# Number after print_r output?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php

  $array = ["test", "1", "2", "3"];

  $id = 0;

  echo "ID: 1 - <pre>",  print_r($array), "</pre><br/>";
```

When I execute the code, the [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0533a1fdae6f6ce2edae8a9cb23d59841cad11be) is the following:

```
ID: 1 - Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
1<br/>
```

If you look closely, you will notice a number after the array output of `print_r`. Why is this number showing up and is there a way to stop it from showing up?

Comment: `print_r($array, true)`

Comment: @splash58 Oh haha. Do you know why the number is showing up though?

Comment: By default `print_r()` writes output instantly. To add the output of `print_r()` inline so to speak you have to tell it not to output to the browser instantly using parameter 2 and setting it to `true` You are seeing the `1` as its the return value from the function call i.e. true

Comment: last 1 - return from print_r

Answer (score 5):

Calling `print_r()` without a second parameter outputs the value and then returns `true` - which is the `1` your getting in the output.  You probably want to use `print_r($array, true)` to get it to return the value as a string and then be able to wrap it in the HTML tags you want.

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense thanks. Will accept the answer once possible.

Answer (score 1):

print_r() without it's second argument will return boolean true, which turns to "1" when converted to a string.
Add `true` as the second parameter to make print_r return it's output.